# How can I change libzmq of pyzmq from 4.1.6 to 4.2.* in Ubuntu?

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I have installed pyzmq by `pip install pyzmq`,then I found a bug in libzmq 4.1.6 which has been fixed in libzmq 4.2.*([issue](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/1588)) . 
So how can I upgrade libzmq ?

env:
libzmq-4.1.6
pyzmq-16.0.3
Python-3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to build PyZMQ again against the new libzmq 4.2. I've used [this guide](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/wiki/Building-and-Installing-PyZMQ) with success.